# Folland Exercise 1.4.21 proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Exercise 21: Let $\mu^*$ be an outer measure induced from a premeasure and $\overline{\mu}$ the restriction of $\mu^{*}$ to the $\mu^*$- measurable sets. Then $\overline{\mu}$ is saturated. (Use exercise 18)

Exercise 18 is basically saying that if $\mu^{*}$ outer measure induced from a premesure, then for any $E\subset X$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\mu^{*}$-measurable set $A$ such that $E \subset A$ and $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^* (E) + \epsilon$.

*Proof.* Let $E \subset X$ be a locally measurable set. It suffices to show that for any $A \subset X$ such that $\mu^*({A}) < \infty$, $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A\cap E^c)$. So let  $A \subset X$ such that $\mu^*({A}) < \infty$. There exists a  $\mu^{*}$-measurable set $B$ such that $A \subset B$ and $\mu^*(B) \leq \mu^*(A)+1 < \infty$ (using exercise 18, setting $\epsilon = 1$). Since $B$ has finite outer measure, $B \cap E$ is measurable, by the definition of locally measurable. Thus $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap (B \cap E)) + \mu^*(A \cap (B \cap E)^c).$ Since $A \subset B$, $A \cap (B \cap E) = A \cap E$. Also,  $A \cap (B \cap E)^c = A \cap (B^c \cup E^c) = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap E^c).$ Since $A \subset B$, $A\cap B^c = \emptyset$. So $A \cap (B \cap E)^c = A\cap E^c$. Therefore, $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A \cap E^c).$ Thus $E$ is measurable.
I didn't find any problems with this proof, but intuitively i think my proof is wrong because it is way too simple.

Comment: Are you proving the quoted statemen to or exercise 18?

Comment: @Jake Freeman, I'm trying to prove the quoted statement. Use exercise 18 is given as a hint for the quoted statement